# G++ no matching constructor for initialization

Tags: constructor, g++, matching

I have the following classes in a .h:

```
class Register {
  int content;

 public:
  Register ();
}reg;

class Simulator {
  int op1, op2, initial_pos;
  Register RA, RB, RC, RD, PC, SP, FP;
  bool zero, neg;
  int mem[1024];

 public:
  Simulator (int, int, const std::string);
  void Memdump ();
  void Exec_next ();
}sim;
```

and the definition for the simulator constructor is as follows:

```
Simulator::Simulator (int i, int j, int k, std::string fname) {
  FILE* instructions;

  valA = 0;
  valB = 0;
  valC = 0;
  valP = 0;
  valE = 0;
  op1 = 0;
  op2 = 0;
  zero = false;
  neg = false;
  valid1 = false;
  valid2 = false;
  PC::content = 0;
  FP::content = j;
  SP::content = j;
  initial_pos = k;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    mem[i] = 0;

  //Read input file
  if (instructions = fopen (filename, 'r') == NULL) {
    cout << "Error 404: file not found\n";
    exit (404);
  }
  for (int i = 0; !feof (instructions); i++)
    fscanf (instructions, "%d\n", &(mem[i + initial_pos]) );
  fclose (instructions);
}
```

but when i try to compile this code i get the following error message:

> ./TP1.h:45:2: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
>   'class Simulator'
>
> }sim;
>
> ^
>
> ./TP1.h:42:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 3
>   arguments, but 0 were provided
>
> Simulator (int, int, const std::string);
>
> ^
>
> ./TP1.h:10:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy
>   constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided

why isn't g++ finding the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I'm using 1 less argument than required.